# Want to buy above market price?

Tags: stocks

If stock A is currently at level of Rs. 104, but I know that if this will cross Rs. 106, then it will go to Rs. 107 level definitely, ..Then is it possible to place limit order to purchase that stock at 106 level and sell at 107 level?

Comment: Keep in mind that if you *know* that the stock will behave that way due to insider information not available to the general public (as opposed to *strongly suspecting* that development due to your intuition and experience with stock markets) and act on that information, then you are doing [insider trading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insider_trading), which can be illegal under some circumstances.

Comment: Nothing is for sure.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer - apart from the "know" and "definitely" the OP is basically asking if an order can be placed automatically to buy only if price goes to 106 or above. The answer is yes - a conditional order can be placed for such a situation.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do this buy placing a conditional order to buy at market if the price moves to 106 or above. Once the price hits 106 your market order will hit the market and you will purchase the stock at 106 or above.

You can also place a tack profit order at 107 linked to your initial conditional buy order, so that once you buy order is executed and you buy at 106, a take profit order will be executed only if the price reaches 107 or above.

If the price never reaches 106, neither your market buy order or take profit order will hit the market and you won't buy or sell anything.

Answer (score 1):

Buy and sell orders always include the price at which you buy/sell. That's how the market prices for stocks are determines. So if you want to place a buy order at 106, you can do that.

When that order was fulfilled and you have the stock, you can place a sell order at 107. It will be processed as soon as someone places a buy order at 107.

Theoretically you can even place sell orders for stocks you haven't even bought yet. That's called [short selling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_(finance)). You do that when you expect a stock to go down in the future. But this is a very risky operation, because when you mispredict the market you might end up owing more money than you invested. No responsible banker will even discuss this with you when you can not prove you know what you are doing.

Comment: This is not really what the OP is after. The OP is only wanting to buy if the price moves to 106, not put a price to buy at 106 whilst the price is still at 104.

Comment: also this is untrue: *It will be processed as soon as someone places a buy order at 107.* Stocks are traded at the price which results in the highest transaction volume.